# Use PHP variable in Javascript won't work

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have the following code in my HTML document:

HTML

```
<span id="indicator" class="label label-success">Online</span>
```

JS/PHP

```
<?php $result=1; ?>    <!-- Just for testing -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var status = '<?php echo $result; ?>';
    window.onload=function(){
    var ind=document.getElementById('indicator');
    if(status==1){
       ind.innerHTML='Online';ind.className='label label-success';
    }else{
       ind.innerHTML='Offline';ind.className='label label-danger';}
    }
</script>
```

But nothing happens. When i use Firebug to debug it seems that the variable "status" is not the "1" - it is "'`? php echo $result; ?>` ';". So it will never set my inner HTML to "Online".
What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: just remove the quotes around php coding in script

Comment: remove the quotation marks, youre entering a string

Comment: Are you sure, you have that JS in PHP file? its not JS file? Thats why it has value `"'? php echo $result; ?> ';"`.

Comment: HTML document with PHP :O -
Make PHP page!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure, you have that JS in PHP file? its not JS file? Thats why it has value `"'? php echo $result; ?> ';"`.

So its `index.html`. Are you sure your PHP accept this extension as PHP?

And also, you are missing `}`:

```
<?php $result=1; ?>    <!-- Just for testing -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var status = '<?php echo $result; ?>';
    window.onload=function(){
    var ind=document.getElementById('indicator');
    if(status==1){
       ind.innerHTML='Online';ind.className='label label-success';
    }else{
       ind.innerHTML='Offline';ind.className='label label-danger';}
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Well, this won't work for me. I saved your code in a .php and included it in my html. And i added the "header"-thing from Smuufs post. But it won't work.

Comment: Erm...no? I created a .php with your code above, loaded it in my html with <script type="application/javascript" src="js_code.php"></script> Why do you think i am kidding...i just want to do things right :(

Comment: Yes, i did that because when i just use your code it won't work either. So i'm wondering what i'm doing wrong here :/

Answer (score 0):

And are you sure you're processing the .js file with PHP?
If you're not, then do this:

```
<?php
  header('Content-type: application/javascript');
  $result = 1;
?>

<script type='application/javascript'>
  var status = <?php echo $result; ?>;
  window.onload = function(){
    var ind = document.getElementById('indicator');
    if(status == 1) {
      ind.innerHTML = 'Online';
      ind.className = 'label label-success';
    } else {
      ind.innerHTML = 'Offline';
      ind.className = 'label label-danger';
    }
  }
</script>
```

And save it into **js_code.php**, which you then load into HTML file like this

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="js_code.php"></script>
```

And voila! You now have a JavaScript file first processed by PHP.

Comment: When i do it just like you said i also get an error from firebug says that the syntax in the js_code.php is wrong. To be specific "<?php" is highlited as wrong. Confusing.

Comment: If the file is really processed by PHP, there simply cannot be `<?php` in that file anymore. Are you sure you do have PHP properly installed and working on your machine?

Comment: Just copied everything to my server but it isn't working. PHP should work fine since every other PHP works.